# access url helpers from rails engine generated pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I actually have this in rails layout:

```
<li><%= link_to "Blog Posts", root_path %></li>
```

But when I added `blogit` gem it started to following error for urls associated with `blogit`:

```
undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f644864ce00>:0x007f6449e8faf8>
```

So I suspect url helpers are not accessible from there. So what can be done to make them accessible ? I have tried by adding this in the layout:

```
<% include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers %>
```

but it could not help me much.

Comment: Try this article http://candland.net/2012/04/17/rails-routes-used-in-an-isolated-engine/

Comment: You should take a look at this [Github Issue](https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit/issues/8).  It looks like there are some configuration options that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<li><%= link_to "Blog Posts", Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_path %></li>
```

assuming in your routes.rb file you have something like:

```
root "home#index"
```

Comment: Thanks(+ 1)looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this goal by adding the main app's `url_helpers` in your engine's `ApplicationController`.

```
module YourEngine
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
    helper Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end
end
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  <li><%= link_to "Blog Posts", main_app.root_path %></li>
```

`main_app` gives you access to all of the url helpers of the host application.

It is described in the Rails documentation at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes and https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html